# Integrate program on webserver

Tags: php

I would like to make use of the tool "PDFToHTML" which you can find [here](http://www.articlediary.com/article/php-script-for-pdf-to-html-conversion-125.html).
Unfortunately, I have no idea on how I need to install this and execute this on my webserver.
I would like to know if some people are familair with this, if there are any tutorials available or something else because i have no idea on what to search for.

Mainly I need help/tutorial on how to:

1. Install the tool on the webserver. (My host is bluehost)
2. Execute the program to create the files
3. This is not necessary, but at the end I would like to zip the files.

Here's some more information but they don't explain on how to install it.
http://www.articlediary.com/article/php-script-for-pdf-to-html-conversion-125.html

Comment: I think http://serverfault.com/ would be a better site to ask this. Even then, please try something yourself first, and if you are getting stuck somewhere, ask a specific question about that where you are stuck at.

Comment: I tried it myself, I even asked people I know. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Wowsers, this is a scary tool.  To execute it you must run it through one of the System commands in PHP, which means you need shell access.

1. If you're on shared hosting, you may not even be able to run that command.  Maybe look through Bluehost's features and see if you can really do that.  Also you could try a simple command like System('ls'); to see if it will even run at all.

If you do have permissions to run shell scripts, go to the link found in the article you pasted:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdftohtml/
and google install tar file on linux.  (If you're on shared hosting you probably can't do that either).

1. Just follow the example they give.
2. Install another package that zips files, like zip.